# How can I access globals directly with Java interop?

Tags: java, interop, intersystems-cache

All of [the documentation I see](http://docs.intersystems.com/ens20122/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BLJV_intro) talks about object persistence.  This is fine and dandy, but I need to be able to access globals directly (like `^SE("stackoverflow","q",34241364,"md")`).

How can this be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible with Globals API, which available with Java eXTreme library (cacheextreme.jar). See [documentation](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20152/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=BXJV_globals). End example:

```
import com.intersys.globals.*;

class FetchNodes {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection myConn = ConnectionContext.getConnection();
    try {
      myConn.connect("User", "_SYSTEM", "SYS");
      NodeReference nodeRef = myConn.createNodeReference("myGlobal");
      // Read both existing nodes
      System.out.println("Value of ^myGlobal is " + nodeRef.getString());
      System.out.println("Value of ^myGlobal(\"sub1\") is " + nodeRef.getString("sub1"));
      nodeRef.kill();   // delete entire array
      nodeRef.close();
      myConn.close();
    }
    catch (GlobalsException e) { System.out.println(e.getMessage()); }
  } // end Main()
} // end class FetchNodes
```